# What's the minimal size of a core dump if I only need stack backtrace?

Tags: linux, gdb, coredump

I want to reduce the size of my core dump files but I really want to make sure the stack backtrace is still there. What's the minimal size of core dump that will ensure the backtrace is there?

Comment: Can you clarify this? I think you mean "what is the minimal coredumpsize ulimit if I only need a stack backtrace", not about alternatives such as setting `core_pattern` or `coredump_filter` to reduce the size. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

This question is bad. Your actual goal was not specified.

First off, stack sizes vary and why would teh kernel start dumping from teh stack in the first place. Maybe it does, but I'm too lazy to check.

Instead I suggest you take a look at abrt/other stuff which can extract needed info before anything hits storage.

Comment: Hi, @koro, it's bad user experience if truncated core dump means losing of stack backtrace. Though I agree with you that kernel might choose most straightforward way to truncate core dump. I know there are alternative approaches for my purpose. Though I'd argue this question is still meaningful for people who wants a definite answer.